# Pick status based on application date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Sample data:

```
ID  Goal    Status              applied_at
A   A       Ongoing             1-Jan
A   B       Applied             1-Feb
B   C       Ongoing             1-Mar
B   D       Rebalanced          1-Apr
B   E       Signed Paperwork    1-May
```

I am trying to pick a `status` per `ID` based on `min(applied_at)`.
Any suggestions how I can do that?

Expected Output:

```
ID  Status           
A   Ongoing                    
B   Ongoing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` is a typical approach:

```
select id, status
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by applied_at) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @user8834780 . . . Yes, you are missing something.  The cumulative minimum of the status column is quite different from the status on the minimum date.

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to use subquery :

```
select t.id, t.status
from table t
where applied_at = (select min(t1.applied_at) from table t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
select t.ID,t.status from your_table t where t.applied_at = 
                       ( select min(applied_at) from your_table t1 
                        where t1.ID =t.ID
                        )
```